# Apache CXF user input sanitation

Tags: soap, cxf, sanitization

I am developing some Apache CFX Web Services (note: I am not using Spring) and I am concern about injections and security in general. I think I am safe when it comes to SQLi once the code reaches my database, but how can I sanitise the input that comes from SOAP?

(ie. How can I prevent any other type of injection? Is there a way to read the raw number of bytes the user has sent? Becuse when objects are sent it is very unflexible to go one by one manually checking the size of each attribute)

Ideally I am looking for a library that supports the sanitisation of user input from SOAP.

Comment: one of good practices is to enforce schema validation with strict schema definitions (even for its  performance cost)